# Node error: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

I have been working on a project lately and it requires me to find and update my database by finding the id of something selected, but for some reason, it gives me an error of "cannot read property "id" of undefined"

Here is my .ejs file which the user is suppose to select the going button

```
<h1><%=term%></h1>
<article>
<% for(var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){ %>
<section>
<div class="bars">
  <p class="names"><a href = <%=bars[i].url%>><%= bars[i].name %></a></p></br>
  <div class="image"><img src=<%=bars[i].image_url%> width="150px"></img></div></br>
   <a id="<%= bars[i].id %>" class="going btn btn-primary"><%=bars[i].totalAttending%> Going</a></br>
  <%= bars[i].location.address1 %></br>
  <%= bars[i].rating %></br> //user is suppose to select here
</div>
</section>
<%}%>
</article>
```

Here is my code for the index.js file which selects the object and returns the id

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$('.going').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/auth/github',
        data: {
            id: $(this).attr('id')
        },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data === 'done') {
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert(data)
            }
        }
    });
});

$(' input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    localStorage.lastSearch = $('input[type="text"]').val()
});
});
```

And here is how I am using the id to update my database

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    //First check to see if user is attending that bar, if so decrement
    Venue.findOneAndUpdate({
        id: req.data.id,
        totalAttending: 1,
        usersAttending: req.user.username || req.user.displayName
    },
        { $set: { 'totalAttending': 0 } },
        { new: true },
        (err, venue) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!venue) {
                Venue.findOneAndUpdate({ id: req.data.id },
                    { $inc: { 'totalAttending': 1 }, $addToSet: { 'usersAttending': req.user.username || req.user.displayName } },
                    { new: true },
                    (err, venue) => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        res.send('done');
                    });
            } else {
                res.send('done');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Does anyone know why it returns the error and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default id is defined as `_id` not just `id`. Try adding that underscore.

Comment: Thanks so much, @C.Amirani, turns out I also forgot to use the body-parser in my server.js file, and everything works fine now!